# aiogram aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Button_user_privacy_restricted E

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

```py
kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=message.from_user.full_name, url=message.from_user.url))

await bot.send_message(config['OFFER_CHAT'], f'#id{message.from_user.id}', reply_to_message_id=m[0].message_id, reply_markup=kb)
```

`aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Button_user_privacy_restricted`

Почему так происходит? И как исправить?